# Kendo UI Grid items per page dropdown dances/auto closes when the grid is displaying at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, angularjs

The issue seems to be in the latest Kendo UI Grid Demo as well.
http://dojo.telerik.com/AJApA

The grid works in small screens like tablets.
Open the above demo link in large screen and it works fine.
Move the slider between the code and result window to the left to the maximum and try again. Upon clicking the dropdown, the dropdown list blinks and closes off.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't add comments yet, but try to change the `pageSize` to number 5, it works this way, if you increases the number after 2 pages it will blinks again.
It is strange, but some how it works when it is 5.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                    },
                    pageSize: 5
                }
```

instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                    },
                    pageSize: 20
                }
```

Comment: What about the "All" items per page ?

Comment: When I clicked on "All" items per page and scrolled down to the bottom and clicked on dropdown, the issue still exists

Comment: No. I have opened a thread in Kendo forum. http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-grid-all-items-per-page-dropdown-dances-auto-closes-when-the-grid-is-displaying-at-the-bottom-of-the-page